# Flutter animation translate 2 different movements

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

Im having problems with flutter animations. I want to move a circle to bottom and when complete move right. Like the letter "L".

Im only moving the circle to bottom and I can update the data. I have to update the begin an the end on the tween or I have to use 2 different animations?

Is the same object and the same type of animation.

```
AnimationController controller;
  Animation<double> animationRigth;
  double begin;
  double end;


@override
  void initState() {
    controller = new AnimationController(
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1600), vsync: this)
      ..addListener(() => setState(() {}));

    begin = 200;
    end = 500;
    animationRigth = Tween(begin: begin).animate(controller);

    super.initState();
  }


IconButton(
  onPressed: () {
 animation = Tween(begin: begin, end: end).animate(controller);
  controller.forward();
  },
)


AnimatedBuilder(
  animation: controller,
  builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
    return Transform.translate(
      offset: Offset(200, animation.value,),
      child: circle());
    });
  }
)
```

Comment: please add your controller and animation variables detail because animation depends on it.

Comment: hello, thanks for your answer, I edit the post with the controller and the variables